# Metamask reporting wrong balance in Ganache account?

Tags: metamask

I'm a little mystified why when I run Ganache and link to an account using the proviate key, Metamask reports an account balance of 200606 ETH when the account has only 100 ETH in it according to Ganache.  What's going on with that?

As you can see the account address I've connected to is the same, 0x6439Dff47254a6F3B78544cE47708AA700a1512a (this copied from Metamask)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It seems MetaMask has problems getting the currency right.

Adding ETH as the currency symbol in the network settings should solve your issue.